# Android export apk throws ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, android-library

I've created a project that have 3 dependencies for 3 different **android projects marked as libraries**. I **managed to run the application from eclipse** and everything works fine.

The problem: I've **exported the project as a signed apk**. The **apk** was created and I was able to run it on my device but **when it tries to access an activity that resides in one of the android library my app crashes** with ActivityNoFoundException. It seems that the android library projects were not added in the final apk, but why?

All the manifest files are merged into the main manifest file.

What can be the problem? Thank you!

Comment: Is the activity declared in your manifest (not the library manifest) ?

Comment: Yes. The all the manifest files are merged into the main manifest

Comment: Does your project use proguard obfuscation?  it's possible the activity names are being obfuscated and therefore would not match up with what's in your manifest.  Usually obfuscation isn't run when you run the app from an IDE so could also explain why it works there.  You could also try unzipping the apk and looking inside to see what is actually making it in.

Comment: Hmm..yes it does. Maybe this is the source of my problems. I'll check it out and let you know. Thank you for the hint @Nick

Comment: @Nick you were right! Thanks! The proguard messed it! You may write an answer to thumb it up

Comment: Added it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your project use proguard obfuscation? it's possible the activity names are being obfuscated and therefore would not match up with what's in your manifest. Usually obfuscation isn't run when you run the app from an IDE so could also explain why it works there. You could also try unzipping the apk and looking inside to see what is actually making it in